# how can i solve the link error My visual C++ 2008 with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am the very bignner for the OpenCV.

I’ve just install the OpenCV and make the C++ program as follow.

My compiler is visual C++ 2008.

```
# include "highgui.h"
void main() {
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/OpenCV/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/images/lena.png",-1);
  cvNamedWindow("lena",0);
  cvShowImage("lena",image);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&image);
}
```

But it could not be built with the error message, and I cannot solve this problem.

The error message is as follow.

(My compiler is Korean Version and I translate the error message into English.
 And the English is poor, but you may understand how it was processed.)

```
1>------ begin build: project: image1st,: Debug Win32 ------ 
1> compiling)
1>image1st.cpp
1>c:\vs2008\ccp_file\image1st\image1st.cpp(17) : warning C4700: not inetialized ‘image’ use local variable
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>linking
1>image1st.obj : error LNK2019: _cvReleaseImage External Symbol(refrence positon: _main function) not defined.
1> image1st.obj : error LNK2019: _cvWaitKey External Symbol(refrence positon: _main function)not defined.
1> image1st.obj : error LNK2019: _cvShowImage External Symbol(refrence positon: _main function)not defined.)
1> image1st.obj : error LNK2019: _cvNamedWindow External Symbol(refrence positon: _main function)not defined.)
1>image1st.obj : error LNK2019: _cvLoadImage External Symbol(refrence positon: _main function)not defined.)
1>project: warning PRJ0018 : can not find the next environment variable.
1>$(OPENCV_DIR)
1>image1st – errors: 6, warning: 1
```

And I modified the visual c++ environment are modified as follow.

And I input “$(OPENCV_DIR)\include” in the “Additional Include Directories” entry,

and make the “Additional Dependencies” entry to include the next .lib file as the OpenCV Tutorials
Release 2.3 guides.

- ‘opencv_core231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__imgproc231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__highgui231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__ml231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__video231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__features2d231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__calib3d231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__objdetect231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__contrib231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__legacy231d.lib’
- ‘opencv__flann231d.lib’

And the include and library directories of visual c++ environment are modified as follow.

For library:

- $(VSInstallDir)lib
- $(VSInstallDir)
- $(FrameworkSDKDir)lib
- $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib
- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\i386
- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib
- $(VCInstallDir)lib
- C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib     // modified
- C:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib      // modified
- C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib     // modified
- C:\opencv\build\x64\vc9\lib      // modified
- C:\opencv\build\gpu\x86\lib     // modified
- C:\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib     // modified

For include:

- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
- $(WindowsSdkDir)\include
- $(FrameworkSDKDir)include
- $(VCInstallDir)include
- C:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv     // modified
- C:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2    // modified
- C:\opencv\build\include             // modified

Comment: Lib names are weird.  Look for a .lib whose name resembles cvaux.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that your processor can't recognize the user vairble OPEN_CV 
first, make sure that the system\user vairble is correct. 
in order to do that go to  system properties --> on advance menu --> to go Enviroment variables -->  make sure your system variable is correct , if not please create one with the path to your  open cv library location.

[image: user variables]

it's seems like you are doing everything right , 
I believe your problem is that you have missed some at the  post build step ...

Second , you'll have to copy the dll files from the openCV library to the location of your project. 
in order to do so , please include an appropriate path on the post build step on your project. 
go to your project : properties ... watch the picture [image: here]

and include the command:

```
copy "C:\OpenCV2.31\CMake_Build\bin\Debug\*.dll"
copy "C:\OpenCV2.31\CMake_Build\bin\Debug\*.pdb"
```

Good luck

S

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems, that the compiler cannot find the OpenCV libraries or has trouble identifying the right one.

Make sure, that the needed libraries (i.e. `opencv__xxx.lib`) can be found in the directories you specified in the  library directories (`C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib` etc.) Also, you should only specify the directories for your platform, i.e. only `vc9` (since you're using VS2008) and `x86`/`x64` depending on your architecture.

The `PRJ0018` warning indicates, that the `OPENCV_DIR` environment variable is not set. You can do this in the System properties dialog (usually you get it by right-clicking on "My Computer" and select "Properties", in Win7/Vista you have to go to "Extended System settings") on the "Extended" Tab, there's a Button "Environment variables". But if you already modified the include directories, you can omit the "Additional include directories" setting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

may be it can help you.

[Using OpenCV 2.1 with MS Visual Studio](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++)

[OpenCV 2.1.0 with Visual Studio 2008](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2008)